# Set text field value instantly (without emulated typing)

Tags: set, copy-paste, watir

I'm using the below command to set a text input value to "some value" however the value isn't set instantly, instead it's set as if it were typed by a user. That's ok for small values, but I'm using this method to insert a big text inside a textarea and I don't want the emulated typing to occur, I would like the value to be set instantly, like with a copy/paste.

```
browser.text_field(:attr,"val").set "some value"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Shubham's reply I was able to track back the relevant method (.speed= at [watir reference](http://wtr.rubyforge.org/rdoc/1.6.5/)). **Fast speed isn't a copy/paste** emulation although it goes really fast. The proper speed option is **:zippy** and you set it as follows:

```
browser = Watir::IE.new
browser.speed= :zippy
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you to use speed :fast instead for all other text_fields, but the ones, which are large use #value= instead. If you use :zippy then no JavaScript events will be triggered and it might cause you painful moments...

Answer (score 2):

Before initializing watir add this option.

```
$FAST_SPEED  = 1
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I was able track the relevant method. I edited my question with the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This also works:

```
browser.text_field(:how => "what").value=("some value")
```